# probability of white balls is drawn in $7$ th draw

Tags: probability

> A box contain $24$ identical balls, of which $12$ white and $12$ blacks. The balls are drawn  at random from the box one at a time with replacement, The probability that  a white ball is drawn  $4$ th time on the seventh draw is

what i try

probability of white ball is drawn is $\displaystyle \frac{\binom{12}{1}}{\binom{24}{1}}=\frac{12}{24}=\frac{1}{2}$

probability of black ball is drawn $\displaystyle 1-\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: You can use the binomial distribution for this

Comment: @DMH16 Directly Binomial (and nothing else) is wrong in this case. The $7$th draw is specified to be a white ball.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin Whoops I read the problem wrong, I thought the OP meant 4 white draws in a total of 7 draws, didn’t notice that the last should be a white one. Anyways, you can still use a binomial, just fixing the 7th position as a drawing a white one; it’s a trivial fix. My comment either way was not wrong. I simply stated that you need to use the binomial, which in fact, you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the successive trials are independent, and since 
$$ P( \mbox{White} ) = P( \mbox{Black} ) = \frac{1}{2}, $$
therefore the probability of $4$th white on the $7$th draw is
$$ { 6 \choose 3} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^3 \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^3 \frac{1}{2} = \frac{5}{32}. $$

Comment: Thanks so much. small correction in last line $\displaystyle \frac{5}{32}$